# If $|(ax + by)(ay + bx)| \le x^2 + y^2$ holds for all real $x$ and $y$, then prove $a^2 + b^2 \le 2$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

How do I go about proving the following statement?

> Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Let the inequality
> $$|(ax + by)(ay + bx)| \le x^2 + y^2$$
> hold $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that
> $$a^2 + b^2 \le 2$$

I have been going at this problem for an hour now and I can't seem to find a reasonable approach, I always have a "leftover" term that I can't get rid of.

Comment: The problem is part of an [ongoing competition](https://om.mimuw.edu.pl/static/app_main/problems/om72_1.pdf).